# Kivy widget give Type error in some cases

Tags: python, inheritance, kivy

I have a widget ButtonEditBox that work in the test file (the code provided below) but when the widget is used in a bigger application the error is created

```
self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0_dev-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/lang.py", line 1611, in _apply_rule
self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0_dev-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/lang.py", line 1608, in _apply_rule
 child = cls(__no_builder=True)
File "/home/johan/workspace/Archery/misc.py", line 58, in __init__
 super(ButtonEditBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

The widget

```
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import  Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


__all__ = ['ButtonEditBox']


class ButtonEditBox(BoxLayout):

    label = ObjectProperty(0)
    input = ObjectProperty(0)
    on_text_validate = ObjectProperty(0)

    #__events__ =('on_press')


    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_press')
        #next line same as "/home/johan/workspace/Archery/misc.py", line 58
        super(ButtonEditBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def set_label(self, name):
        self.label.text = name
        #self.update_callback()

    def set_box(self, name):
        self.input.text = name

    def on_press(self):
        print "on-pressed"
        pass

    def text_pressed(self):
        print "text_pressed"
        self.dispatch('on_press')
        return True



Builder.load_string("""

<ButtonEditBox>:
    input: input
    label: label

    height: self.input.height + self.label.height

    id: layout1

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: 'Button 1'
        id: label
        size: len(self.text) * root.input.font_size, 2 * root.input.font_size
        size_hint: None, None
    TextInput:
        id: input
        text: 'Button 2'
        multiline: False
        size: root.width - root.label.width - root.spacing, 2 * self.font_size
        size_hint: None, None
        on_double_tap: root.text_pressed()

""")



if __name__ == '__main__':

    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


    def update_game_name(instance, text=None):
        if text != None:
            print "To update text field: "  + str(text)
            app.input.text = text
        else:
            print "To show popup "
            pop = Popup(content=ButtonEditBox(), 
                        title='Change entry name'
            )
            pop.content.set_label('Entry name')
            pop.content.set_box(app.input.text)
            pop.bind(on_dismiss=lambda x: update_game_name(x, text=pop.content.input.text))
            pop.size_hint = [.5, .5]
            pop.open()
        pass

    app = ButtonEditBox()

    class WidgetApp(App): 

        def build(self):
            app.bind(on_press=update_game_name) 
            app.set_label("test name")
            return app

    WidgetApp().run()
```

Does Kivy use old or new python classes?

How can I resolve error message given?

Comment: I don't know what would cause this, it seems good to me. Is there any chance of something like having defined some other class with the same name in the larger project?

Comment: I did not found any other class with the same name.

Comment: The bigger project was rebuild file for file. The error re appear when a file was included containing from misc import *; import misc; reload(misc). The error disappeared when the last two statements was removed.